# Encoding Issue Exporting from PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I've got a query I'm running and exporting the data from PostgreSQL.  I'm ending up with a ton of Â characters in place of apostrophes and such when I open it in Wordpad or Excel.  Quite frankly, I can't get my ahead around any of this encoding crap.   How when I'm exporting the data do I get those characters to show right?

Comment: See if you can specify the encoding when opening with WordPad or Excel.  Try UTF-8 first.

Comment: Obligatory link to [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), which may help you understand some of the issue.  Can you tell us about your client encoding and table encoding setup, and what language you're using to process the results of your queries?

Comment: "I can't get my ahead around any of this encoding crap" If you are in the programming world, you MUST spend the necesary time (one weekend should suffice) to understand charset encodings (specially Unicode, see link above) and get confortable with these issues. It's obligatory knowledge, and highly non ephemeral.

Comment: very true leonbloy.  I have actually managed to coast by many many times with googling and random blind luck for so long. I could probably save myself a ton of time if I actually try to actually understand it.  Great link to that article Charles, can't believe I haven't come across that before.

Comment: I am not familiar with PostgreSQL as we're just trying to import some old data into our new system, but, the settings for that table are for the encoding to be UTF8.  There's nothing encoding wise that I'm knowingly change when I export(using pgAdmin)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I followed the instructions here and it did it. Thanks everyone anyway.

http://www.wohill.com/a-workaround-for-encoding-problems-in-excel/

Comment: The link's website is considered harmful by my browser. Maybe you could replicate the info here on SO (or somewhere else)...?